# whats the alternative for .dropdown-submenu in BootStrap 3.3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

In bootstrap 2.3 we had a  `.dropdown-submenu` to create submenu.whats the alternative for this in Bootstrap 3.3?

> Sub menus on dropdowns
>   Add an extra level of dropdown menus, appearing on hover like those of OS X, with some simple markup additions. Add `.dropdown-submenu` to any li in an existing dropdown menu for automatic styling.

[source](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/components.html)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use following clases

```
.dropdown --> Indicates a dropdown menu
.dropdown-menu --> Builds the dropdown menu
```

Example:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Dropdown Example
<span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Reference [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_ref_comp_dropdowns.asp) and [Here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_dropdowns.asp)